# How do i solve setting an array element with a sequence error in Keras model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train this model to detect and read Morrocan licence plates but when

i run the file i get the following error : ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Here is the full code to the model :

```
import numpy as np
import gen
import itertools
import cv2
import itertools

import keras
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, LSTM, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K

import tensorflow as tf

DIGITS = "0123456789"
DIGITS_E = "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
DIGITS_E1 = "0123456789 "
DIGITS_0 = "123456789"
BARRE = "|"
LETTERS = "\u0648\u0647\u062f\u062c\u0628\u0623"
CHARS = LETTERS + DIGITS + BARRE + DIGITS_E + DIGITS_0 + DIGITS_E1


def diff_letters(a,b):
    return sum ( a[i] != b[i] for i in range(len(a)) )

def unzip(b):
    xs, ys = zip(*b)
    xs = np.array(xs)
    ys = np.array(ys)
    return xs, ys

def code_to_vec(p, code):
    def char_to_vec(c):
        y = np.zeros((len(CHARS),))
        y[CHARS.index(c)] = 1.0
        return y

    c = np.vstack([char_to_vec(c) for c in code])

    return np.concatenate([[1. if p else 0], c.flatten()])

def letter_probs_to_code(letter_probs):
    return "".join(CHARS[i] for i in np.argmax(letter_probs, axis=1))

def read_batches(batch_size):
    g = gen.generate_ims()
    def gen_vecs():
        for im, c, p in itertools.islice(g, batch_size):
            yield im.reshape([1,64,128]), code_to_vec(p, c)
    while True:
        yield unzip(gen_vecs())

class print_codes(keras.callbacks.Callback):      
    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        cont = 0;
        erros = 0;
        score_results = self.model.predict(val_batch[0])
        real_scores = val_batch[1];
        for i,j in zip(score_results,real_scores):
          probs1 = i[1:].reshape([7,36]);
          probs2 = j[1:].reshape([7,36]);
          code1 = letter_probs_to_code(probs1);
          code2 = letter_probs_to_code(probs2);
          erros = erros + diff_letters(code1,code2);
          cont = cont + 7;        
          #print("{:.2f} - {} <-> {} - {}".format(i[0], code1, j[0], code2));
        print("Acc: {}%".format(100*(cont-erros)/cont));


for x in read_batches(100):
  val_batch = x;
  break;

c_test = print_codes()

def lr_schedule(epoch):
  if (epoch<=10):
    return 1.0*(0.1**int(epoch));
  else:
    return 1.0*(0.1**int(epoch/10))


###########################################################


batch_size = 50
input_shape = (1, 64, 128)
learning_rate = 0.001;
steps_per_epoch = 500;
epochs = 1000;

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(48, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape, data_format='channels_first', padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#model.add(Conv2D(48, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 1), strides=(2, 1)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

model.fit_generator(read_batches(batch_size),steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, callbacks = [c_test], epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
```

and here is the full Traceback of the error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 124, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(read_batches(batch_size),steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, callbacks = [c_test], epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 217, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1217, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2655, in _call
    dtype=tf.as_dtype(tensor.dtype).as_numpy_dtype))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Can someone help me out I tried fixing it myself, but I failed, and I can't

pinpoint where the error originates from